# Move JoyStick in exact Pixels

Tags: python, mouse, virtual, pixel, joystick

I am working on a project where i want to move a virtual joystick (vJoy) x number of pixels. However I am unable to find a method of converting pixels into the Joystick's Axis (Axis are -32768 to 32767). An example might be more helpful to explain:

lets say i would like to move 50 Pixels on the x axis in a given time of 100 milliseconds, therefore i would have to find the exact axis force between -32768 to 32767 which would move the object 50 pixels in the given time.

As i require a great deal of accuracy in the movement, i am stumped on a method which would accomplish this task. Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Figure out the total range the physical joystick axis can traverse. You've given min and max values of -32768 to 32767, for a total range of 65535.
2. Figure out the total range of pixels you want the virtual joystick (vJoy) to be able to move. Let's say it starts out at pixel position 0, and its min and max allowed values are -100 and 100. This gives us a total range of 200.
3. Now, figure out how many units the physical joystick should travel per virtual joystick movement. We get that by dividing: 65535 / 200 (physical joystick range / virtual joystick range), which gives us 327.675. This number in hypothetical terms would mean "for every pixel the virtual joystick travels, the physical joystick travels 327.675". Let's assign this value to the variable "axis_per_pixel".

   4. Finally, if we know that the value axis value has changed by amount "a" (from your example 50), we can determine how much the physical joystick value needs to change by multiplying: a * axis_per_pixel. In our example, this would be 50 * 327.675, which is 16383.75. So, when the virtual joystick position increases by 50, the physical joystick position should increase by 16383.75 to match.

I'll give a code example. You tagged this as Python, but I'm going to answer in JavaScript because my Python is still a bit rough. Hopefully it's clear enough.

```
function getPositionIncrease(
  minPixelValue, // lowest allowed pixel position, ie -100
  maxPixelValue, // highest allowed pixel position, ie 100
  minAxisValue, // lowest allowed axis value, ie -32768
  maxAxisValue, // highest allowed axis value, ie 32767,
  pixelDelta, // what amount the pixel position has changed by
) {
  const distPixel = maxPixelValue - minPixelValue;
  const distAxis = maxAxisValue - minAxisValue;
  const axisPerPixel = distAxis / distPixel;
  const axisDelta = pixelDelta * axisPerPixel; // how much the physical axis needs to change to match
  return axisDelta;
}
```